# Cannot set-up MyPHPadmin in Apache

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin

I just started using Apache, but when I try to run myPHPadmin, I get this error message:

## 1 - Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/w1/5yx2p9mj7w9bm67gdwhqxwsr0000gn/T/#sql1ba_3_0.MYI' (Errcode: 13)

Another post in the Stack Overflow suggested changing the permissions on the XAMPP file, my.cnf, with this command:

**sudo chmod 600 my.cnf**

I tried running the code in Mac Terminal, but the result was "No such file or directory."

Does anyone know what I should try next?

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission problem on your datadir (where MySQL wants to write files). Normally, at MySQL installation, correct permissions are set for the user who runs mysqld.

Are you sure that MySQL was installed correctly as part of XAMPP installation?